# Identify wire's ID's/index numbering to select them for creating SETS

Tags: python, abaqus

Good day everybody, hope everything is okay.

I'm using Abaqus software to create (small) pipelines with wires. For that i use excel as the pre-processor for the raw input data (coordinate-points -> point-to-point of the center-lines and center-to-end [fittings/flangs] all these distances come from the isometric drawings).

After that i run a vba macro on excel, from those data points its creates wires and voilá! There is the modeled(wired) pipeline in python scripted for Abaqus.
And for the final touch i need to set the Loads and steps for calculus (stress and displacement analysis).

So its just 1 pipeline, with 2 different PIPE SIZES, so what i want to do is the following (my opinion, it might not be the best ofc):

On loads i chose the set of pipes, for exemple: set-6inch
That set represents all the wires that are labled
/SET for 6" pipes
But for that to happen i need 1st to create sets only on certain wires from the pipeline, and for THAT i need the wire Indexes that i cant find anywhere.

It uses this code on the .jnl file (.txt format) when i manually create sets:

`mdb.models['model-1'].parts[part-1].set(edges=mdb.models['model-1'].parts['part-1'].edges.findAt(((5.0,1.25,0.0),),((1.25,0.0,0.0),),),name='set-6inch')`

I cant find the meaning AND MAKE SENSE of these arguments from the edges.findAt command anywhere (probably i'm very bad on advanced searching methods): (5.0,1.25,0.0)

And those are not the coordinates of the 2 points/vertices of the wire no way. Not even the index number of the datumspoints nor the coordinates of the middlepoint of the wire.
Actually the number 5 and 0 are similar to the coordinates from the datumpoints but the 1.25 isn't.

Cant find it on the manual, like i said, i probably set my eyes on it and didnt understand it or just passed trough it.

Answer (score 0):

These arguments are coordinates at which a specified edge(s) can be found.

About `findAt` method from the Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide:

> This method returns the object or objects in the EdgeArray located at
> the given coordinates.
>
> findAt initially uses the ACIS tolerance of 1E-6. As a result, findAt
> returns any edge that is at the arbitrary point specified or at a
> distance of less than 1E-6 from the arbitrary point. If nothing is
> found, findAt uses the tolerance for imprecise geometry (applicable
> only for imprecise geometric entities). The arbitrary point must not
> be shared by a second edge. If two edges intersect or coincide at the
> arbitrary point, findAt chooses the first edge that it encounters, and
> you should not rely on the return value being consistent.

If you are creating your parts using python scripting what is the problem to create sets directly after the part definition?

```py
m = mdb.models['model-1']
my_part = m.parts[part-1]
my_set = m.Set(name='MySet-1', edges=my_part.edges)
```